# XSLT - How to ignore a sub tag in XML if supertag contains a particular term

Tags: xslt

I am trying to change my XSLT so that when a super tag in my XML contains a particular word the sub tag is not selected.

In this example I do not want the sub tag `<para>` displayed when the super tag `<formalpara>` contains the word "Galaxy"

Thanks in advance.

My XML

```
<formalpara>
Galaxy
<para>
<bridgehead>Galaxy Zoo</bridgehead>
    <sliceXML>Galaxy</sliceXML>
    The human eye is far better at identifying characteristics of galaxies 
    than any computer. So Galaxy Zoo has called for everyday citizens to 
    help in a massive identification project. Well over a hundred thousand 
    people have helped identify newly discovered galaxies. Now you can, too.
</para>
</formalpara>
```

My XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="results"/>
    <xsl:message>FROM simpleHMHTransform XSLT8</xsl:message>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="results">
    <xsl:for-each select="//formalpara">
        <xsl:call-template name="formalpara"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:for-each select="//para">
        <xsl:call-template name="para"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="formalpara">
<div id="formalpara">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="para">
<div id="para">
    <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/>
</div>
</xsl:template>
```

My current output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" id="formalpara">
Galaxy

</div><div xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" id="para">


    The human eye is far better at identifying characteristics of galaxies 
    than any computer. So Galaxy Zoo has called for everyday citizens to 
    help in a massive identification project. Well over a hundred thousand 
    people have helped identify newly discovered galaxies. Now you can, too.
</div>
```

My desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" id="formalpara">
 Galaxy
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really do `xsl:apply-templates` instead of calling named templates. You could then add this template:

```
<xsl:template match="formalpara[contains(text(),'Galaxy')]/para"/>
```

I can give a full example later.

---

Full Example:

**XML Input**

```
<formalpara>
    Galaxy
    <para>
        <bridgehead>Galaxy Zoo</bridgehead>
        <sliceXML>Galaxy</sliceXML>
        The human eye is far better at identifying characteristics of galaxies 
        than any computer. So Galaxy Zoo has called for everyday citizens to 
        help in a massive identification project. Well over a hundred thousand 
        people have helped identify newly discovered galaxies. Now you can, too.
    </para>
</formalpara>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="formalpara">
        <div id="formalpara">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="formalpara[contains(text(),'Galaxy')]/para"/>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <div id="para">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<div xmlns:sparql-results="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#" id="formalpara">
    Galaxy
    </div>
```

NOTE: I also changed the `contains()` to `contains(text(),'Galaxy')` so it only looks at the text that is a direct child of `formalpara`.

Comment: Thanks DevNull, a full example would be great, il try and figure it out in the mean time with this help.